# How do I delete these unclickable shapes in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

There are hidden shapes in the artwork and when I hover over the shape they appear but they are not clickable to delete. How do I delete these four, large rectangles?

[image]

Comment: Check at first is there a clipping mask or several of them. This can be seen in the layers panel or as well if Object > Clipping mask > Release is selectable. Clipping mask can be seen as a ghost when the mouse hovers on it. Releasing them reveals do they anything useful. They can be inserted to hide some unwanted parts or they appear without asking when one uses Illustrator for Images which are made with different, probably newer version.

Answer (score 1):

The rectangles would indicate a **Mesh Object**. Possibly an *Envelope Mesh* which is used to distort artwork into various shapes.

You can...

- Simply hit the delete key twice to remove the mesh object. This will **also remove the artwork** within the mesh.
- Select the mesh and choose `Object > Envelope Distort > Edit Contents`. This will allow you to alter what is *inside* the mesh without removing the mesh.

For more information on Envelope Meshes, see the Adobe Help files linked to below:

- [Adobe Help: Envelope Meshes](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/reshape-using-envelopes.html)